# PS 1.6: Run cronjob manually

Tags: cron, prestashop-1.6

I am beginner in PrestaShop 1.6. I have a Cronjob module and I configure it. I use the Basic mode Cron. How can I run the Cronjob manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run a cron job manually by opening the URL

If you have a module that uses cronjobs they give you a URL so you can add that URL to cronjob automatic task

Example: Module as this cronjob: http://www.example.com/cronjob123.php

If you copy and paste it in the browser it will run the cron and the task will be completed